# StateFlow don't emit when the new value same last value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow, kotlin-sharedflow

I have a login form. I use `StateFlow` to send `LoginResult` (after call API) from `ViewModel` to `Activity`. In the Activity, I will show an error dialog if login failed.
It works well for the first time but from the second time I login failed, the error dialog won't show again. I tested both `.value` and `.emit` on `StateFlow`

```
private val _loginResult = MutableStateFlow(LoginResult())
val loginResult: StateFlow<LoginResult> = _loginResult

fun login(email: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        when (val result = loginRepository.login(email, password)) {
            is Result.Fail-> {
                _loginResult.value = LoginResult(error = "Login failed")
                // _loginResult.emit(LoginResult(error = "Login failed")) same issue
            }
            ...
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: StateFlow does not emit duplicate value. you can user SharedFlow  to solve your problem.

Comment: @OmidFaraji yes, I have solved it in my answer. It takes me some time to solve this problem so I post it here

Answer (score 4):

For this case, I use `SharedFlow` so my `Activity` still able to collect the new value even it same the last value

```
private val _loginResult = MutableSharedFlow<LoginResult>()
val loginResult: SharedFlow<LoginResult> = _loginResult

...
_loginResult.emit(LoginResult(error = "Login failed"))
```

Another possible solution but it's not good is change my current `data class LoginResult(...)` to `class LoginResult`. Then every new instance of `LoginResult` will different

Comment: Why is SharedFlow better than StateFlow for this?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky so normally, I use StateFlow to store UI state, and SharedFlow to emit event. we shouldn't use StateFlow for event, because if you rotate the screen, the event can trigger again.

Answer (score 1):

That's by default. What you could do is to emit one value when the login is in progress, before emitting the result. That way you would have a sequence like:

`in_progress -> error -> in_progress -> error`

Apps usually display a spinner or something when the `in_progress` or `loading` or whatever is emitted.